# get user contribution number in pybossa

Tags: python, postgresql, pybossa

I'm building a project in Pybossa. 
When I export users, on exported user data I want to include a field which to get the number of contributions that each user did.

On PyBossa project statistics page I see that there is table with all contributors which is generated from this method in python:

```
    userStats = dict(
        geo=current_app.config['GEO'],
        anonymous=dict(
            users=users_stats['n_anon'],
            taskruns=users_stats['n_anon'],
            pct_taskruns=anon_pct_taskruns,
            top5=users_stats['anon']['top5']),
        authenticated=dict(
            users=users_stats['n_auth'],
            taskruns=users_stats['n_auth'],
            pct_taskruns=auth_pct_taskruns,
            top5=users_stats['auth']['top5']))
```

Based on this I can't define a method which will return user submission by id? I know that I can do a query, but I asking here if there is aleardy a method which I can use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is not implemented. However, you can build a plugin yourself that will include that information, or if you prefer send us a pull request to include that feature. Happy to merge it into our upstream code base of PYBOSSA.

See documentation about our plugin architecture here: http://docs.pybossa.com/en/latest/plugins.html?highlight=plugin

See how to contribute here: https://github.com/PyBossa/pybossa/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md

Cheers,

Daniel

Comment: thank you very much. I have another question if you can answer. Is already any method in pybossa to check if the current user contributed in a task in pybosa when loading a task that has already been processed, and no longer requires redundant entry?

Comment: PYBOSSA handles that for you automatically :-) Basically, every time you check the endpoint SERVER/api/project_id/newtask the server checks which tasks are available for the user (authenticated or not) that has not participated before.